# input php_strip_whitespace with a stream

Tags: php

Is there any way to use a memory stream as input for [php_strip_whitespace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.php-strip-whitespace.php)?

I've tried this, but it's not working because php://memory is recreated each time a handle is open:

```
  $stream = 'php://memory';
  $fp = fopen($stream, 'r+');
  fwrite($fp, $this->get_code());
  rewind($fp);

  var_dump(php_strip_whitespace($stream)); -> empty
```

I've also tried the data:// stream but I get this error:

```
php_strip_whitespace(): data:\\ wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0
```

I want a global solution independent of the server configuration.
Thank you

Comment: Hm, I doubt it, for the reason you mention. Is just defining a [`StreamWrapper`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.streamwrapper.php) not an option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I got this solution, thanks to Wrikken:

```
class DummyMemoryStreamWrapper {

const WRAPPER_NAME = 'var';

private static $_content;
private $_position;

/**
 * Prepare a new memory stream with the specified content
 * @return string
 */
public static function prepare($content) {
    if (!in_array(self::WRAPPER_NAME, stream_get_wrappers())) {
        stream_wrapper_register(self::WRAPPER_NAME, get_class());
    }
    self::$_content = $content;
}

public function stream_open($path, $mode, $options, &$opened_path) {
    $this->_position = 0;
    return TRUE;
}

public function stream_read($count) {
    $ret = substr(self::$_content, $this->_position, $count);
    $this->_position += strlen($ret);
    return $ret;
}

public function stream_stat() {
    return array();
}

public function stream_eof() {
    return $this->_position >= strlen(self::$_content);
}
}


  $php_code = $this->get_code();
  DummyMemoryStreamWrapper::prepare($php_code);
  $source = php_strip_whitespace(DummyMemoryStreamWrapper::WRAPPER_NAME . '://');
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just create a temporary file?

```
<?php
$temp = tmpfile();
fwrite($temp, "writing to tempfile");
$info = stream_get_meta_data($temp);
var_dump(php_strip_whitespace($info['uri']));
fclose($temp); // this removes the file
?>
```

Comment: This is the current way I do it and that I want to change